# How can I generate Test result (CSV)file and JTL file in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

After test run, How can I generate Test result (CSV)file and  JTL file in jmeter. Because, this jtl file using to generate Dashboard report in jmeter3.0.

So, kindly give me solution.

Thanks,
Vairamuthu.

Comment: In GUI mode (as far as I could see so far) you have to specify the JTL filepath *before* you run the test; via the *Write results to file / Read from file* option under *Summary Report*, *Results Tree* etc.

Answer (score 9):

1. JMeter test result .jtl files should be generated during each test run given you provide results file location via `-l` command line argument
2. .jtl files format defaults to CSV
3. You can generate dashboard after test execution as follows:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t /path/to/test.jmx -l /path/to/results/jtl -e -o /path/to/html/report/folder
   ```

References:

- [Full list of JMeter command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Dear Abby BlazeMeter, How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)

Answer (score 2):

Jmeter 4.0 solution :  (I believe it could be executed on older version but I did not tried)

1. open command prompt and go to Jmeter -> bin folder 
   //for example : C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin
2. Issue this command (**remember it's a one single command**) -

jmeter -n -t C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\res\nonGUI.jmx -l C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\res\log\logResult.log -j C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\res\log\logFile.log -e -o C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\res\report

3. Above command will give you

(a) **Actual log** 
// C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\res\log\logFile.log

(b) **Result with pass/fail status**
C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\res\log\logResult.log

(c) **HTML report** 
C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\res\report\index.html

Answer (score 1):

You could resolve it easier by setting the property in jmeter.properties file as below.

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer

or

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Sample_Result_Save_Configuration

you have other components on the page like http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report